# Is there a way to add an activity to a group?

Tags: activities

I would like to add an activity to all the records in a query I pulled from Civi.  Is there a way to globally add an activity?  If possible, I would like to avoid editing each record individually.

Answer (score 2):

From a Search you can use the Actions button to add an Activity to all those contacts. It gives you the option to either create one Activity that all contacts are on, or one per each contact.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Is there a way to upload a list and add an activity to all the records using Contact ID?

Comment: When you import contacts, you have the option of adding the imported contacts to a (new) group, so then from that group you could add the activity as above.

Comment: or you could import your contact using an external id. then use that same external id to import activity for each of them (ie just 'make up' the activity on the s/sheet and import like that)